# How to make window content transparent just like [phw/peek]

Tags: macos, swiftui, desktop-application

I am new to swift and xcode, I want create a macos app just like [peek](https://github.com/phw/peek) (a screen GIF recorder).

Now I created a window with toolbar follow the tutorials. My question is, how to make the content area of the window be transparent, and ignore mouse event pass to the bottom of the window.

Thank you ^_^ !

[image]

This is the screenshot of [peek](https://github.com/phw/peek):
[image]

Comment: Hmm well peek is open-source, so you can see exactly the code that does this

Comment: And also isn't peek for Linux and not macOS?

Comment: @aheze peek is based on GTK, but I want to using SwiftUI to get a similar effect.